# Combing mutliple python functions and a text file into and something that could be run on any windows computer

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

So I made a pretty cool hangman game with a text document that has all the possible words. Also a python file that was just functions for my main file to use. I want to send this to a friend who doesn't use python nor have any python stuff installed on their computer. I don't think pyinstaller will work because it is multiple files. Is there a way that I can get it working on computers without python?

Edit: I'm very new to all this stuff. Just a heads up

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what version of python you used, there are several solutions:

1. Check out [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial) (but afaik this is only a supported for python 2.7.x)
2. [pyinstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/downloads.html)
3. [cx_Freeze](https://anthony-tuininga.github.io/cx_Freeze/)

All of them are pretty well documented.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, python is an interpreter not a compiler. As such any python file has to be INTERPRETED by the INTERPRETER. Unlike java and C++ where you could compile the code to an output file that is executable on multiple platforms.